# sitecore xconnect - Value cannot be null

Tags: xconnect

I recently installed new sitecore 9.3 instance locally and working as expected, now i'm trying to move everything to dev environment and sitecore xconnect instance is giving error see blow,

**Source Error:**

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   System.Collections.CollectionBase.OnValidate(Object value) +14763684
   System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value) +43
   : dBrw<oaA"'"\\n61;?-%6>')..ctor(String ) +297
   ⁪‏⁮⁯⁯‏‭‬‫⁯‎‮‎‎‌⁭‬⁯⁭⁭‌‪‮‬‌‮⁪‭‎‭‍‬⁫⁬‎‭‎⁭⁭‪‮.​‌⁫⁮‬‍‎⁪‫‎‮‪⁫⁪‭‎⁬⁯⁪⁯​‍‍⁯⁯⁫‌‫⁫⁯​​‫‪‍‏⁯‎⁭‫‮(⁪⁫‌‎⁯‌‬‌⁭‮‪⁮‎​‌⁯‍​⁬⁪‬‎‮⁭⁪‌‫⁮‫​⁮‌⁯‎⁪‪‬⁬‪‬‮ ) +256
   ‮‍⁫‫⁯‫‎⁭⁭⁫‌‎‮‭‮‭‮‌‪⁮‪‎‮‍‌‌⁬‬‍‍‌‪‌⁮‌‭⁬‬‭‌‮.⁪⁫​‬‬‭⁮‏‮‭‌⁮⁫​‭⁪‍‎‮‮‪⁮‎⁪‬‭‎‫⁬⁮⁭⁬‭‍⁪⁪⁪⁭⁮⁮‮() +230
   ⁭‭⁯⁪‮‮⁪‬⁬‬⁭‎⁪‬⁬‪⁭‭‎‫‮⁭‮‏‭‮‏​⁯‌⁫⁭​‌⁭‌‭⁭‮‫‮.‍⁪‫⁬‮‪‬⁪‪‎‪‭⁮⁮‮‌⁫‪‮‎‪⁯‍‪‌‍‏‎‫‏⁯⁫‫‎⁮⁮‍‮⁮‬‮(Boolean ) +105
   ⁭​‫⁬⁯‌‍‬​⁭⁬‏‌‪‫⁫⁯⁭‭⁮‎‏‪‮⁭⁮⁬‌⁫‎⁪​⁪‫‪‪‍⁪⁯‫‮.⁭​⁮‍⁯‮⁭⁯‮⁭⁫‬‫‮‪‭​‏‍​⁬⁭⁬‏‪‬⁯⁭‍‏⁪⁬‍⁭⁬​‏⁯‌⁫‮(‮‌‪​‭⁭‭⁯‎⁮‬‬‍‪‮⁯‫⁮⁫‌‮‬⁬‬⁬‫‭‮⁬⁫‎‭‬‫‌⁮‬⁫‏⁭‮ ) +663
   ‍⁯‍⁪⁪⁬‪​‌‪‫‪‬⁯⁮⁫⁮​⁮​⁬‭⁯‪‎‌⁭‌‏‍⁯‌⁫⁬‎‌⁫‍⁯‭‮.⁭​⁮‍⁯‮⁭⁯‮⁭⁫‬‫‮‪‭​‏‍​⁬⁭⁬‏‪‬⁯⁭‍‏⁪⁬‍⁭⁬​‏⁯‌⁫‮(String , String , String , IDictionary`2 ) +602
   Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.ConsumptionTracking.Initialize(String licenseFileOrXml, String roleName, String environmentName, String sitecoreVersion) +326
   Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.UseXConnectServiceInitializationConfiguration(IServiceCollection collection, IConfiguration configuration, String[] configurationSectionNames, String initializationSectionName, Boolean validateConfiguration) +428
   Sitecore.XConnect.Web.WebApiConfig.ConfigureServices(HttpConfiguration config) +432

[ApplicationException: Exception trying to initialize Service Collection and Provider for WebAPI Dependency Resolver, Inner Exception: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   Sitecore.XConnect.Web.WebApiConfig.ConfigureServices(HttpConfiguration config) +1108
   System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action`1 configurationCallback) +46
   Sitecore.XConnect.Web.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +503

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception trying to initialize Service Collection and Provider for WebAPI Dependency Resolver, Inner Exception: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +517
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +185
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception trying to initialize Service Collection and Provider for WebAPI Dependency Resolver, Inner Exception: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +714
```

Not sure what I've missed out.

Version info: 
Sitecore 9.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this! The issue was the app pool identity because on local SIF creates local certificate dedicated to that instance of service, whereas i attached original certificate which wasn't accessible.

Comment: Hi, which steps exactly have you done to fix the apppool identity?